# How to Convert underscore separated string to Capitalized String

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
var str = "edit_country"
```

I want to split words based on underscore and  make one string "Edit Country"
Here first letter after space should be capital.

Answer (score 1):

You Should try this.

```js
var str = "edit_country";
str=str.split('_');
alert(str[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+str[0].slice(1));
alert(str[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+str[1].slice(1));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: something different from duplicate.